# how to remove openid since google auth is depreciated?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

As per the latest circular, google plus oauth is depreciated.
As per my understanding, i should be concerned only if i am using plus.me in my code.

My code:

```
google = oauth.remote_app(
    'google',
    consumer_key=app.config.get('GOOGLE_ID'),
    consumer_secret=app.config.get('GOOGLE_SECRET'),
    request_token_params={
        'scope': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'],
            'access_type': 'offline',
            'approval_prompt':'force'
    },
    base_url='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method='POST',
    access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
)
```

However, i can still see openid in my google developer console.
Scopes for Google APIs

- email
- profile
- openid

Also, API response is returning scope as plus.me

```
Response from google auth: {
u'access_token': u'ya29.GluoFWy', 
u'id_token'hbGciYA', 
u'expires_in': 3600, 
u'token_type': u'Bearer', 
u'scope': u'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 
u'refresh_token': u'1/jgwO0w'}
```

I have checked that i am not accessing plus.me anywhere. I am really confused if i need code changes or not.

Comment: Me too.  When I use OpenID Connect, I replace it from the 'plus.me' scope to ’openid' scope, but redirect URL from Google is given `plus.me` scope.  
  In this state, I'm concerned that OpenID Connect will be affected by Google+ API shutdown.

Comment: In my case.    Token request URL is `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&hd=${HOSTED_DOMAIN}&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=openid+email&redirect_uri=${CALLBACK_URL}&state=${NONCE}`.    Redirect URL from Google: `${CALLBACK_URL}?state=${NONCE}&code=${CODE}&scope=openid+email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&authuser=0&hd=${HOSTED_DOMAIN}&session_state=${SESSION_STATE}&prompt=none`

Comment: Currently, Google seems to respond and plus.me scope is not appended.  I hope not to revert.