# What should be replaced with 'plus.me' scope on G Suite Marketplace?

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace, google-openidconnect

Until currently we have used `plus.me` (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me`) scope for OpenID Connect on G Suite Marketplace.[But 'plus.me' scope will discontinue with Google+ API shutdown.](https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown)

Google Sign-in(And Google OpenID Connect) replace to 'openid' scope from 'plus.me'. My code has been already migrated but G Suite Marketplace is not accept 'openid' because it only accept URL format.

[image: input openid scope on G Suite Marketplace SDK's Configuration]

What should be replaced with 'plus.me' scope on G Suite Marketplace?

UPDATED:
Even if neither 'openid' nor 'plus.me' is registered, I confirmed that OpenID Connect is work without OAuth confirmation screen.

If 'openid' scope is a specification that does not need to be registered on G Suite Marketplace SDK and this specification will be keep, I would like to get reference written by Google or hear from staff of Google.

Comment: Since I could not get an answer here, I registered in the issue tracker.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124650795

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, [the issue is fixed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124650795#comment6) and 'openid' scope is be able to register.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [migration](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/quick-migration-guide) guide:

> Most G+ Sign In applications requested some combination of the scopes:
>   `plus.login`, `plus.me` and `plus.profile.emails.read`.

New Scopes:

```
•   email (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email)
•   profile (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile)
•   openid (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me)
```

It's better to switch to Google Sign-in authentication system. Google now recommends requesting an ID token and sending that ID token from your client to your server. ID tokens have cross site forgery protections built-in and also can be statically verified on your server, thus avoiding an extra API call to get user profile information from Google’s servers. Follow the instructions for [validating ID tokens on your server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token).

Comment: I have already checked it.  I am in trouble because 'openid' scope URL is 'plus.me' scope.

Comment: Yes, my code is already migrated. I want to replace to 'openid' scope on G Suite Marketplace but there does not accept it.  Currentry I reluctantly have remained set 'plus.me' scope on there.  
I would like to know how to setup official on there that will not be affected when the Google+ API is shutdown. I contacted GCP support, but I heard that G Suite Marketplace is not supported, so I post it here.

Comment: There is also a problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54452938), and I can not be relieved despite the migration.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. If the GCP says so that it's not supported then I can't help you with your problem :(

Comment: Sorry I made you misunderstood with wrong sentences. They said **GCP Support do not support about G Suite Marketplace.**